# What is the best way to reuse business logic across Informatica ETL and ASP.NET CRUD pages?

Tags: asp.net, etl

I don't know the first thing about Informatica but I am looking for ways to resolve duplicating business logic that for inserting and updating records in a table. The problem is doing it in an efficient manner.

1) We have web pages that insert, update and delete records one at a time.

2) We have Informatica ETL load programs that take records from a staging (temp) table and load them. This process is rather a black box to me, but I know that Informatica has efficiencies built in, such as reading fairly large tables in memory, etc, so many records can be validated quickly.

I understand that if the Business edits were placed in web service that this web service could be reused by both the web page doing CRUD operations as well as the Informatica load process, but how do you do this efficiently? Passing one record at a time to a web service would kill the ETL efficiency. So would passing thousands of records.

I feel like I am in the dark cause I don't know how Informatica works.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Step one: I'm afraid you'll have to go learn about InfoMatica. It may operate in a totally different manner than you imagine, making all your assumptions false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to go learn about InfoMatica. It may operate in a totally different manner than you imagine, making all your assumptions false